# Dropdown list doesn't work as a dropdown (button)

Tags: html, ruby, haml

I have this dropdown list:

```
- if current_user
    %li.header__list-item.dropdown
    %a.dropdown-toggle{:href => "#", "role" => "button", "data-toggle" => "dropdown", "data-target" => "#"}
      Account
      %b.caret
    %ul.dropdown-menu{"role" => "menu"}
      %li
        = link_to "Change your password", edit_user_registration_path
      %li
        = link_to t('devisegeneral.sign_out'), destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: 'header__link header__link--active'
  - else
    %li.header__list-item
      = link_to t('devisegeneral.sign_in'), new_session_path(:user), class: 'header__link header__link--active'
```

so that when a user clicks in `Account`, these two links `change your password` and `sign_out` should appear. But instead like this I have them both displayed all the time and the "button" account doesn't work. Is there anything I am missing, because I am loosing a lot of time and can't fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using this template instead of yours:
https://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_dropdowns.asp
I have used it multiple times and It works great!